# Using SearchView to retrieve matching values in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, pattern-matching

I have an activity where I want to search matching values in my firebase database. I don't want anything to appear up until something is typed on my `SearchBar`, after something has been typed I want to display values that match what was typed in my `SearchBar`. I have created an activity and it is not displaying anything up until you type something, my problem is that it does not retrieve the matching values but it shows everything within my database directory.

This is my activity:

```
public class MyUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivit {

private Toolbar toolbar, searchtollbar;
private RecyclerView mUsersList;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;


Menu search_menu;
MenuItem item_search;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search Users");
    //toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    setSearchtollbar();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDisplayName(String name){

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setUserStatus(String status){

        TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
        userStatusView.setText(status);


    }

    public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);

        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(userImageView);

    }


}


public void setSearchtollbar()
{
    searchtollbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.searchtoolbar);
    if (searchtollbar != null) {
        searchtollbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_search);
        search_menu=searchtollbar.getMenu();

        searchtollbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                else
                    searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        item_search = search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item_search, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                }
                else
                    searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when expanded
                return true;
            }
        });

        initSearchView();


    } else
        Log.d("toolbar", "setSearchtollbar: NULL");
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void circleReveal(int viewID, int posFromRight, boolean containsOverflow, final boolean isShow)
{
    final View myView = findViewById(viewID);

    int width=myView.getWidth();

    if(posFromRight>0)
        width-=(posFromRight*getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material))-(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material)/ 2);
    if(containsOverflow)
        width-=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material);

    int cx=width;
    int cy=myView.getHeight()/2;

    Animator anim;
    if(isShow)
        anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0,(float)width);
    else
        anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, (float)width, 0);

    anim.setDuration((long)220);

    // make the view invisible when the animation is done
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            if(!isShow)
            {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    // make the view visible and start the animation
    if(isShow)
        myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // start the animation
    anim.start();


}

public void initSearchView()
{
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();

    // Enable/Disable Submit button in the keyboard

    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

    // Change search close button image

    ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);


    // set hint and the text colors

    EditText txtSearch = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
    txtSearch.setHint("Search..");
    txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txtSearch.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));


    // set the cursor

    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    try {
        Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.search_cursor); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            callSearch(query);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            callSearch(newText);
            return true;
        }

        public void callSearch(String query) {
            //Do searching
            Log.i("query", "" + query);

            if(!query.equals("")){

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

                        Users.class,
                        R.layout.users_single_layout,
                        UsersViewHolder.class,
                        mUsersDatabase

                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, Users users, int position) {

                        usersViewHolder.setDisplayName(users.getName());
                        usersViewHolder.setUserStatus(users.getStatus());
                        usersViewHolder.setUserImage(users.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());

                        final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                        usersViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MyUsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);

                            }
                        });

                    }
                };

                mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

            }

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,true);
            else
                searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            item_search.expandActionView();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
    }

   }
```

How can I implement the match function to retrieve what's matching in my database?

Comment: Is it required for you this difficult `SearchView` initialization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter unable to populate result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908750/firebaserecycleradapter-unable-to-populate-result)

Comment: You can also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846631/i-cant-see-any-firebaserecycleradapter-items-on-my-layout/48851402). That tutorial is wrong.